# gdata to java object mapping

Tags: java, xml, gdata-api

hi 
I started learning google data api. 
I have one question 
What will be the best way of parsing xml google data xml ?

1 > Should I go with manually parsing xml ?

Or

2 >  XML to java object mapping technique ?

I am thinking about going with 2 way, As it will require writing less code from my side. 
But I don't know how slow it will be in comparison to 1 way.

How slow is xml to java mapping technique ?

Is there any other better way to parse gdata xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How slow is xml to java mapping
>   technique ?

The answer to this question depends on what you are comparing the xml to Java mapping technique to.  Many object-to-XML solutions have been around for quite a while and have learned a number of tricks to do this conversion.

> Is there any other better way to parse
>   gdata xml ?

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

I'm not that familiar with the Google Data API, but after a quick google, it appears to be related to Atom which can easily be handled by any of the JAXB implementations:

- [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/) (reference implementation included in Java SE 6)
- [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)
- [Apache JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/)

For an Atom example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

With JAXB you can also start with your own object model and add annotations to apply the XML mapping:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

MOXy also contains an XPath mapping extension that makes mapping your object model even easier:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Caster project. Judging from your question, i don't think you would want to go though the trouble to parse the XML using the correct schema and create POJO's to match them (which is troublesome anyway).

I used Caster sometime ago, it is not the best, but got my problem solved pretty fast.

http://www.castor.org/